# How to get array of float audio data from AudioQueueRef in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-audio, avaudiorecorder, audioqueue

I'm working on getting audio into the iPhone in a form where I can pass it to a (C++) analysis algorithm. There are, of course, many options: the AudioQueue tutorial [at trailsinthesand](http://trailsinthesand.com/exploring-iphone-audio-part-3/) gets things started.

The audio callback, though, gives an `AudioQueueRef`, and I'm finding Apple's documentation thin on this side of things. Built-in methods to write to a file, but nothing where you actually peer inside the packets to see the data.

I need data. I don't want to write anything to a file, which is what all the tutorials — and even Apple's convenience I/O objects — seem to be aiming at. Apple's `AVAudioRecorder` (infuriatingly) will give you levels and write the data, but not actually give you access to it. Unless I'm missing something...

How to do this? In the code below there is `inBuffer->mAudioData` which is tantalizingly close but I can find no information about what format this 'data' is in or how to access it.

AudioQueue Callback:

```
void AudioInputCallback(void *inUserData,
    AudioQueueRef inAQ,
    AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer,
    const AudioTimeStamp *inStartTime,
    UInt32 inNumberPacketDescriptions,
    const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescs)
{
    static int count = 0;
    RecordState* recordState = (RecordState*)inUserData;    
    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(recordState->queue, inBuffer, 0, NULL);

    ++count;
    printf("Got buffer %d\n", count);
}
```

And the code to write the audio to a file:

```
OSStatus status = AudioFileWritePackets(recordState->audioFile,
                false,
                inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                inPacketDescs,
                recordState->currentPacket,
                &inNumberPacketDescriptions,
                inBuffer->mAudioData); // THIS! This is what I want to look inside of.
if(status == 0)
{
     recordState->currentPacket += inNumberPacketDescriptions;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  // so you don't have to hunt them all down when you decide to switch to float: 
  #define AUDIO_DATA_TYPE_FORMAT SInt16

  // the actual sample-grabbing code:
  int sampleCount = inBuffer->mAudioDataBytesCapacity / sizeof(AUDIO_DATA_TYPE_FORMAT);
  AUDIO_DATA_TYPE_FORMAT *samples = (AUDIO_DATA_TYPE_FORMAT*)inBuffer->mAudioData;
```

Then you have your (in this case `SInt16`) array `samples` which you can access from `samples[0]` to `samples[sampleCount-1]`.

Comment: this "samples" array, how many second of sampling it contains?
this is this binary representation of the recorded audio?

Comment: "samples" contains one buffer's worth of samples. The length is seconds depends on the buffer size and sample rate: 512 samples at 44.1kHz is 512/44100 = .011609977 sec.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not work for me, I was getting the wrong sample data itself.(an endian issue) If incase someone is getting wrong sample data in future, I hope this helps you :

-(void)feedSamplesToEngine:(UInt32)audioDataBytesCapacity audioData:(void *)audioData {
    int sampleCount = audioDataBytesCapacity / sizeof(SAMPLE_TYPE);

```
SAMPLE_TYPE *samples = (SAMPLE_TYPE*)audioData;
//SAMPLE_TYPE *sample_le = (SAMPLE_TYPE *)malloc(sizeof(SAMPLE_TYPE)*sampleCount );//for swapping endians

std::string shorts;
double power = pow(2,10);
for(int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
{
    SAMPLE_TYPE sample_le =  (0xff00 & (samples[i] << 8)) | (0x00ff & (samples[i] >> 8)) ; //Endianess issue
    char dataInterim[30];
    sprintf(dataInterim,"%f ", sample_le/power); // normalize it.
    shorts.append(dataInterim);
}
```